# Aurelia load routes dynamically / from fetch

Tags: aurelia

I want to load menu options dynamically. so I'm wondering the best approach

I am able to use the code below to add routes after the page is loaded. This works for normal navigation, but does not work during a refresh.

Can configure router return a promise / how do I load menu items into the route?

```
 @inject(HttpClient)
 export class DocumentMenu {
  router: Router;
  documents : IDocument[];
  heading = 'Document Router';

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {}

 activate(): void {

    this.http.fetch('http://localhost:17853/Document/GetDocuments?folderID=13244')
      .then<IDocument[]>(response => response.json())
      .then<IDocument[]>(docs => {    
      if ( docs ){
        for( var doc of docs){
          this.router.addRoute( { route : doc.DocumentID.toString(), name : doc.Name, moduleId: './documents/document', nav:true, title: doc.Name });
        }
        this.router.refreshNavigation();
      }
      return docs;
    });

 }

configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {

  var routes = new Array();
  routes.push( 
  { route: 'index', name: 'index-name', moduleId: './documents/index', nav: false, title: 'Documents' } );
  routes.push(       { route: '', redirect: 'index' } );

  config.map( routes );
  this.router = router;
}
}
```

Comment: Instead of adding routes dynamically, you could add all of them statically, and then use an authorise pipeline to check whether the user can access it or not

Comment: @FabioLuz would work except I don't know what the routes will be. its a bit like a shallow tree structure where the user can select a folder which has somewhere between 0 and 15 documents. I want the documents to be the nav options

Comment: have you tried doing in the constructor?

Comment: @Matt-McCabe just did and it worked, will post answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This does not answer your question, but I think it may be helpful to you and others with a similar issue.

**The Dynamic Route Anti-Pattern**

Your application has a number of different routes, all of which vary based on the state of the application. Therefore, you must first fetch the data, and then build the routes, and then register them with the router.

The reason this is an anti-pattern is because you will continuously need to update the router based on the state of the application, when Aurelia itself is built with static ways of describing dynamic content.

**Dynamically Routing Homogeneous Data**

Let's say you are building Google Drive, and you have a number of various files that could change as the user adds and removes them. For this case you have two categories of routes: Folders and Documents. Therefore, you make one route for each.

```
configureRouter(config) {
    config.map([
        { route: 'folder/:id', moduleId: 'folder' }
        { route: 'document/:id', moduleId: 'document' }
    }
}

class FolderViewModel {
    activate({ id }) {

        // get your specific folder data and load it into your folder view model
        this.fetch('getDocuments?folderId=${id}')
    }   
}

class DocumentViewModel {
    activate({ id }) {

        // get your specific document and load it into your document view model
        this.fetch('getDocuments?documentId=${id}')
    }
}
```

**Dynamically Routing Hetergeneous Data**

Let's say instead you want to build YouTube. When [user mjd10d](https://www.youtube.com/user/mjd10d) logs in, he is welcome to watch videos to his heart's content, but he is not a premium content creator, and doesn't have access to the content creation portion of the site. The best way to handle this is to leave all possible routes in your application, and filter them based on the user's credentials in an `AuthorizeStep`.

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
  config.addPipelineStep('authorize', AuthorizeStep);
}

@inject(UserSession)
class AuthorizeStep {

  constructor(UserSession) {
    this.user = UserSession;
  }

  run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    var instructions = navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions()
    if (!this.authorized(instructions.config)) {
      return Redirect('404');
    }
    return next();
  }

  authorized(routeConfig) {

    // something smart that returns false if unauthorized
    return this.user.permissionLevel > routeConfig.requiredPermission;
  }
}
```

Though not all cases will be authorization related, you can always register your own pipeline step using the [addPipelineStep](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.2.4/doc/article/7) API

Comment: okay this solution wins, but only because of massive scope creep. ( as noted, it doesn't really answer the question )

Answer (score 1):

You can add routes dynamically (at startup or anytime for that matter) by having a single fixed (static) route in the "configureRouter" method (in app.ts), to which you then add all the other routes dynamically, when your fetch completes, like so:

```
configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'SM';

    //configure one static route:
    config.map([
        { route: ['', 'welcome'], name: 'welcome', moduleId: 'welcome/welcome', title: 'Welcome' } 
    ]);

    routeMaps(this.navRepo) //your repo/service doing the async HTTP fetch, returning a Promise<Array<any>> (i.e., the routes)
        .then(r => {
            r.forEach(route => this.router.addRoute(route));
            //once all dynamic routes are added, refresh navigation:
            this.router.refreshNavigation();
        });

    this.router = router;
}
```

The "routeMaps" function is just a wrapper around the repo call and a mapping of the result to the Array of route items.

Answer (score 0):

You can return a promise in activate. if activate() returns a promise, configureRouter() doesnt fire until the promise returned in activate() is resolved.

I ended up preparing the routes in activate like below:

```
activate(){
    return this.http.fetch('url')
       .then(response => response.json())
       .then(docs => {    
           this.routerMapped = docs;
       });       
}

configureRouter(config, router) {
    //build the routes from this.routermapped if necessary
    config.map( this.routerMapped );
    this.router = router;  
}
```

Comment: configureRouter() always fires before activate() :-(

Comment: That seems weird to me. Just tested it, and activate() fires before configureRouter(). Take a look at this [gist](https://gist.run/?id=b4482e1b7ebd85e13d429fa0a44f8745&sha=702644b97ce3777dbb07a2bd88d2ae357d65af51). configureRouter fires 5 seconds after activate, as expected.

Comment: I think it's the difference between an AppRouter and a "regular" router. Your gist is for the app router and my comment was after testing a child router. Thanks for exposing the difference. Aurelia docs say: "Aurelia has two router classes, AppRouter and Router. AppRouter extends the Router class and is the main application router. Router is used for any child routers including nested child routers."

Answer (score -1):

To make this work, I created the routes in the constructor with a synchronous request

```
export class DocumentMenu {
...
routes  : RouteConfig[];

constructor(http: HttpClient) {
  this.http = http;

  var folderID = window.location.hash.split('/')[2]

  this.routes = new Array<RouteConfig>();
  this.routes.push ( { route: 'index', name: 'index-name', moduleId: './documents/index', nav: false, title: 'Documents' });
  this.routes.push ( { route: '', redirect: 'index' } );

  for( var route of this.getRoutes( folderID )){
    this.routes.push( route );
  }
}

getRoutes(folderID: string) :  RouteConfig[]
{
  var routes = new Array<RouteConfig>();
  var docsURL = 'http://localhost:17853/Document/GetDocuments?folderID=' + folderID;

  // synchronous request   
  var docsResp = $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: docsURL,
      async: false,
      cache:false
  }).responseText;

  var docs = JSON.parse( docsResp );

  for( var doc of docs ){
    routes.push( { route : doc.DocumentID.toString(), name : doc.Name, moduleId: './documents/document', nav:true, title: doc.Name });
  }

  return routes;
}

configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {  
   config.map( this.routes );
   this.router = router;
 }
...
```

Comment: make sense, sounds like you might want to wrap that a method to refresh the routes (when a document is added?) or just refresh the page.

Comment: please see my answer for a strategy that might work better for you