# How to load data before configuring the Aurelia router?

Tags: typescript, single-page-application, bootstrapping, aurelia

In my application I dynamically load a set of view identifiers while configuring the router. I then navigate to the first view available:

```
@autoinject
export class App {
    router: Router;

    constructor(private viewManager: ViewManager) {
    }

    configureRouter(config: RouterConfiguration, router: Router) {

        this.router = router;

        config.title = 'My Application';
        config.map([
            { route: [''], name: 'start', moduleId: './views/myapp-start', nav: false, title: 'Start' },
            { route: ['otherroute'], name: 'other', moduleId: './views/myapp-other', nav: true, title: 'Other' }
        ]);
        this.loadViews();
    }

    private loadViews() {
        this.viewManager.getViews().done(views => {
            for (let i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
                this.router.addRoute({ route: `view-${i + 1}`, name: `view-${i + 1}`, moduleId: './views/myapp-dynamic', nav: true, title: views[i], settings: { name: views[i] } });
            }
            this.router.refreshNavigation();
            this.router.navigateToRoute('view-1');
        });
    }
}
```

This works as long as the user calls my application using an URL without parameters, like http://www.example.com. But as soon as the user starts to open the application using one of the dynamic routes like http://www.example.com/#/view-1 the application fails, because on opening the application this route is not yet available.

How can I ensure that dynamic routes are loaded and added before the router kicks in during startup of the application?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647971/aurelia-load-routes-dynamically-from-fetch/37665896#37665896

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis Yes. Thank you. I was thinking of that approach and decided against it, so that I can build the menu from the router config. But that brings no advantage. I will go with the approach you described in your answer. - I voted to close this question as a dupe.

Comment: you're a gentleman and a scholar of stack overflow :)

Comment: @MatthewJamesDavis thank you :)