# How to create dynamic menu in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have Aurelia site and the main menu returns from WebApi in json formate.
For the menu in Aurelia i'm using "router" and the router js code is:

```
export class App {
configureRouter(config, router) {
    config.title = 'Aurelia';
    config.map([
      { route: ['','welcome'], name: 'welcome', moduleId: './welcome', nav: true, title:'Welcome' },
      { route: 'users',         name: 'users',    moduleId: './users',    nav: true, title:'Github Users' },
      { route: 'package-home',         name: 'package-home',    moduleId: './package-home',    nav: true, title:'package-home' },
      { route: 'package-lobby',         name: 'package-lobby',    moduleId: './package-lobby',    nav: true, title:'package-lobby' },
    ]);

    this.router = router;
}}
```

I want all routes will load from json returns from API.
How can i call to the API and fill the routes in the above function ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Aurelia load routes dynamically / from fetch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37647971/aurelia-load-routes-dynamically-from-fetch)

Answer (score 1):

I would inject a http client, make a call to my api, get the json and use a loop to push json objects to my map array. I would gladly write this out but I'm on my phone right now. You should get the basic idea tough

Comment: Hi @Gilbert.
I tried before to inject the http and call my api but it not working ! I can't call the api inside configureRouter function - its throw an exaption